# Listen for track ended event in Spotify iOS SDK

Tags: ios, events, audio, spotify, playback

I'm integrating the Spotify iOS SDK into an app.  How can I listen for track ending events on the `SPTAudioStreamingController` or `SPTTrackPlayer`?

I'm cool with playing, pausing, authenticating, etc.  I just need to grab a track-ended event.

I can see the `SPTTrackPlayerDelegate` has methods, most appropriately, `trackPlayer:didEndPlaybackOfTrackAtIndex:ofProvider`,

but how can I use these?  Is there any examples of usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These classes follow the standard Cocoa delegate pattern.

First, set yourself as the delegate on your track player:

```
self.trackPlayer.delegate = self;
```

Then implement the delegate method in whatever `self` is:

```
-(void)trackPlayer:(SPTTrackPlayer *)player didEndPlaybackOfTrackAtIndex:(NSInteger)index ofProvider:(id<SPTTrackProvider>)provider {
    // Track playback ended.
}
```

Your delegate method will then be called by the track player when appropriate.

Comment: Thank you!

In my case I have used SPTAudioStreamingController to playback, it works just fine.

Two questions to clarify your response: 

1. Should I upcast self to id? Seems the assignment of self to the delegate of SPTAudioStreamingController give a compiler warning stating the delegate expects to be of type id.  Upcasting circumvents the warning:

`code`Assigning to 'id<SPTAudioStreamingDelegate>' from incompatible type 'AudioController *__strong'`code`

2. The delegate MUST implement ALL required methods as listed in the SPTAudioStreamingPlaybackDelegate Protocol Reference?

Comment: Well, the above approach didn't work, we tried listening for the `audioStreaming:didChangePlaybackStatus:` of the SPTAudioStreamingDelegate.  The delegate method is not invoked in any case, pausing, stopping, track ended. 
  
For our needs, we just need to play a track using the track uri, not an album, and it seems the SPTTrackPlayer doesn't do that, confusingly, it plays albums.  
  
We tried `[self.trackPlayer playTrackProvider:albumUri fromIndex:track.trackNumber];`  
  
But this didn't work at all. And the SPTTrack doesn't contain a ref to its album uri. Sigh. What should we do?

Comment: Ok, got it, our problem was: `self.audioController.delegate = self;`  But our interface is set to implement the delegate for <SPTAudioStreamingPlaybackDelegate>  So correct is:  `self.audioController.playbackDelegate = self;`